# Sending large amounts of POST data

Tags: c#, http, post

So i'm making a program where you input some information. One part of the information requires alot of text, we are talking 100+ characters. What I found is when the data is to large it won't send the data at all. Here is the code I am using:

```
    public void HttpPost(string URI, string Parameters)
    {
        // this is what we are sending
        string post_data = Parameters;

        // this is where we will send it
        string uri = URI;

        // create a request
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri); 
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        request.Method = "POST";

        // turn our request string into a byte stream
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data);

        // this is important - make sure you specify type this way
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        // now send it
        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
    }
```

I am then calling that method like so:

```
 HttpPost(url, "data=" + accum + "&pass=HRS");
```

'accum' is the large amount of data that I am sending. This method works if I send a small amount of data. But then when it's large it won't send. Is there any way to send a post request to a .php page on my website that can exceed 100+ characters?

Thanks.

Comment: your problem shouldn't be 100 character limit, don't you have some `?` or `&` in your accum variable?

Comment: I do not :\ I just sent this http://puu.sh/urKY and it didn't even send it.

Answer (score 4):

You're *only* calling `GetRequestStream`. That won't make the request - by default it will be buffered in memory, IIRC.

You need to call `WebRequest.GetResponse()` to actually make the request to the web server.

So change the end of your code to:

```
 // Using statement to auto-close, even if there's an exception
 using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
 {
     requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
 }

 // Now we're ready to send the data, and ask for a response
 using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
 {
     // Do you really not want to do anything with the response?
 }
```

Comment: I'm not wanting a response, I jsut want to send data.

Comment: @DuncanPalmer: Well you still need to call `GetResponse` to actually send the data. So use the code I've posted and ignore the response (other than the automatic status code checking). Note that you *do* still want the `using` statement for it.

Comment: Ok, I did as you said and it still won't send. :(

Comment: @DuncanPalmer: So what happens? Is there an exception? You need to give more details. Ideally, use Wireshark (http://wireshark.org) to see what's happening at the network level.

Comment: Ok so I found the error. After look over my php file it seems that when it attempts to save the file it isn't working. It then found out it was because of what I was trying to save it as (the name) which was  'received-base64_encode(the_data)'. It is fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this way to post JSON data inside the request , I guess it's a little bit different but it may work ,

```
httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RequestURL);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
String username = "UserName";
String password = "passw0rd";
String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    string json = "{" +
                                    "\"user\":[ \"" + user + "\"] " +
                                    "}";
                    sw.Write(json);
                    sw.Flush();
                    sw.Close();
                }
using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
                {


                    //var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        //Now you have your response.
                        //or false depending on information in the response
                    }

                    httpResponse.Close();
                }
```